# kendo datasource server paging and Total in json

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

For my Kendo Datasource resulting json has a column "TotalRecords" how can i set this total to Kendo Datasource total so that my Server paging can work. My code is as below:

```
 var iDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read:
                    {
                        url: service_URL + "GetUnconfirmedppointments",
                        datatype: "json",
                        type: "GET"
                    },
                parameterMap: function (options) {
                    return {
                        appointmentNos: Appointment_Number.value,
                        loadNumbers: Load_Number.value,
                        purchaseOrders: Purchase_Orders.value,
                        dateFrom: Date_From.value,
                        dateTo: Date_To.value,
                        warehouse: warehouses.value,
                        carrierId: cr_carrier_id,
                        sortColum: getOrderBy(options.sort),
                        sortDirection: getOrderDir(options.sort),
                        pageSize: options.pageSize,
                        pageNumber: options.page
                    };
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        APP_APPOINTMENT_ID: { type: "number" },
                        APPOINTMENT_DATE: { type: "date" },
                        LO_LOAD_NUMBER: { type: "number" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            total: function (response) {
               return response[0].TotalRecords;
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
        });
```

Current implementation doesn't work, even if i provided hardcoded total record number, when this datasource is binded to grid the total count only shows the number of records returned in the json which is pagesize.

Comment: Basically your problem is that you have defined `total` outside `schema` instead of inside. See Burke Holland answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my response has total records fields with each record therefore I just moved the below into schema and it fixed it.

```
total: function (response) { return response[0].TotalRecords; }
```

Answer (score 6):

I assume your total is on each and every record?  If it's not, you can just do...

```
schema: {
  total: "TotalRecords"
}
```

Ideally your JSON should be structured like this...

```
{ data:[...], total: 100 }
```

However you can parse the schema if you can't send it over from the server like that. If the total count is attached to every record, you can add a field to hold it and populate it in the parse.

```
schema: {
  parse: function(data) {
      // assign top level array to property
      data.data = data;
      // assign the count off one of the fields to a new total field
      data.total = data.data[0].TotalRecords;

      return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @burkeholland, my problem got resolved. Your response helped me to figure out what was wrong. I just moved the below into schema and it fixed it.  
    total: function (response) {
               return response[0].TotalRecords;
            }